# How do I call a super class method

Tags: ruby

I have two classes `A`, and `B`. Class `B` overrides the `foo` method of class `A`. Class `B` has a `bar` method where I want to call the `foo` method of the super class. What is the syntax for such a call?

```
class A    
 def foo
   "hello"
 end    
end


class B < A
 def foo
  super + " world"
 end

 def bar
   # how to call the `foo` method of the super class?
   # something similar to
   super.foo
 end
end
```

For class methods I can call the methods up the inheritance chain by explicitly prefixing the class name. I wonder if there is a similar idiom for instance methods.

```
class P
 def self.x
   "x"
 end
end

class Q < P
 def self.x
   super + " x"
 end

 def self.y
   P.x
 end
end
```

**Edit**
My use case is general. For a specific case I know I can use `alias` technique. This is a common feature in Java or C++, so I am curious to know if it is possible to do this without adding extra code.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251178/calling-another-method-in-super-class-in-ruby

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In Ruby 2.2, you can use `Method#super_method` now

For example:

```
class B < A
  def foo
    super + " world"
  end

  def bar
    method(:foo).super_method.call
  end
end
```

Ref: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9781#change-48164 and https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/5356938

Comment: Definitely the best answer if your using Ruby 2.2. Simple and a one liner.

Answer (score 26):

You can do:

```
 def bar
   self.class.superclass.instance_method(:foo).bind(self).call
 end
```

Comment: This cannot be the best way to call an overridden method in Ruby, please say it isn't so.

Edit: yeah the comment in the question links to a better option.

Comment: @Vinnyq12 Yes, `alias` is better for specific case, when you know the method you want to call from superclass; but here the OP is asking for a general case, without have to alias every method of superclass.

Answer (score 14):

In this particular case you can just `alias :bar :foo` before `def foo` in `class B` to rename the old `foo` to `bar`, but of course you can alias to any name you like and call it from that. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556118/personal-method-in-ruby/2556380#2556380) has some alternative ways to do it further down the inheritance tree.

Answer (score 6):

You can `alias old_foo foo` before redefining it to keep the old implementation around under a new name. (Technically it is possible to take a superclass's implementation and bind it to an instance of a subclass, but it's hacky, not at all idiomatic and probably pretty slow in most implementation to boot.)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Sony's answer.

In case when you want to call the `method` method on some `my_object` and it's already overriden somewhere several classes higher (like for the `Net::HTTPRequest#method`), instead of doing `.superclass.superclass.superclass` use the:

```
Object.instance_method(:method).bind(my_object)
```

Like this:

```
p Object.instance_method(:method).bind(request).call(:basic_auth).source_location
```