# Extending a Ruby parent class' method with a different-named method

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance

I have a class `Parent` and a class `Child` (which is a <s>child</s> subclass of `Parent`).

- `Parent` has a method called `aaaa`.
- `Child` has a method called `bbbb`.

This is what I want to achieve:

- I want `bbbb` to be an extension of `aaaa`. If I call `aaaa` on a `Child` object, it will run what `aaaa` would normally do, plus whatever else in `bbbb`.
- Calling `bbbb` will do the same as above (runs what `aaaa` would normally do and then do whatever else is in `bbbb`).

This is what I ended up doing:

```
class Parent

  def aaaa
    print "A"
  end

end

class Child < Parent

  alias_method :original_aaaa,:aaaa
  def bbbb
    original_aaaa
    print "B"
  end
  alias_method :aaaa,:bbbb

end

c = Child.new
c.aaaa # => AB
c.bbbb # => AB
```

It *works*. I guess. But it felt really hackish. Plus, a disadvantage of this is that if I wanted to extend `aaaa` with the same name either before or after defining `bbbb`, things get a bit strange.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: The question is... *why*?!

Comment: I could see reasons for doing this. This question has some thoughts about how to handle this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564391/how-do-i-call-a-super-class-method

Comment: What do you mean by "child"? Do you mean subclass?

Comment: You seem to be using the term "extend" in a misleading way. This term is reserved to mean something different than what you probably mean. You should use a different term.

Comment: @sawa: Thanks. What would you suggest me to use though?

Comment: Maybe something like "enhancement", "addition", etc. I am not sure. It is up to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Parent
  def aaaa
    print "A"
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def aaaa
    super
    print "B"
  end
  alias bbbb :aaaa
end
```

Comment: This seemed the obvious answer as soon as I read the question, But the sophistication of how the OP asked the question led me to believe that `super` was not a sufficient strategy for a solution. I will look forward to their response to your answer.

Comment: @NewAlexandria: Nah, I'm just dumb :)

Comment: Dumb enough to ask the question very well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks above answer @sawa
Below my use case I like to share:
super is work by order!

```
   class Parent
      def aaaa
        print "A"
      end
    end
    
    class Child < Parent
      def aaaa
        super
        print "B"
      end
      alias bbbb :aaaa
    end
    
    Class Grand < Child
      def aaaa
        print "C"
        super
      end
    end
    => :aaa
    
    g = Grand.new
    g.aaaa #=> CAB
```