# What does this Ruby syntax mean: if self < Class::Name?

Tags: ruby

I came across this strange syntax I have never seen before:

```
if self < Example::Class::Name
  # do something
else
  # do something else
end
```

What does this check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It checks if `self` is a subclass of `Example::Class::Name`

Check out the [Module docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-3C) :)

Answer (score 2):

### Superclass / Sub-class check.

This is checking if `Example::Class::Name` is the superclass of `self` by this sort of declaration:

```
class DemonstrationClass < Example::Class::Name
  #de body of sub-class

  def cascade *parameters
     #de ...do work
     super #de passes all parameters to the same method name of the super-class.
           #de this even works on an initialize method declaration!
  end
end
```

Instances of `DemonstrationClass` are *sub*-classes of the `Example::Class::Name` *super* class.

Sub-classes have the special feature of being able do things like what I showed in the `cascade` method, and many more things.

**Related questions with more sample code, and examples of associated concepts involved:**

- [ruby inheritance vs mixins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282864/ruby-inheritance-vs-mixins)
- [Can someone explain the Class.superclass.class.superclass paradox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558504/can-someone-explain-the-class-superclass-class-superclass-paradox)
- [How do I call a super class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564391/how-do-i-call-a-super-class-method)